# Laravel 4 authentification issues

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.2 for some time now and I never experienced this issue...
On local machine everything works perfect, but when I uploaded the code to the webserver, for some reason I cannot login, it says that it's logged and when the redirection to the dashboard comes in, I get redirected to login page. I saw that laravel_session doesn't get set and the cookie doesn't get back in the response header.

My auth code is:

```
public function postLogin(){
    $credentials = array(
        'username'      => Input::get('username'),
        'password'      => Input::get('password')
    );
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => '<p class="alert alert-success text-center">Success!</p>',
            'redirect' => route('index')
        ));
    } else {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => '<p class="alert alert-danger text-center">Incorrect data!</p>'
        ));
    }
}
```

the route:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>array('admin.auth')), function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', array('as'=>'index', 'uses'=>'BaseController@getIndex'));
});
```

and filter:

```
Route::filter('admin.auth', function(){
    if(Auth::check() === false){
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
});
```

The redirection to dashboard is made with javascript on the URL that comes with "redirect" parameter on the response.

Also, on top of that, I get a white page with "Redirecting to: ". This doesn't happen on local machine...

Could this be an apache issue regarding that domain? Mentioning that on the same server I have another Laravel website, or another domain, that has the same login script, and there it works without a problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a chance that the host of your web server has abnormal settings for cookies, sessions, and/or redirects. Not really sure what exactly to look for, but it may be worth asking your host if there are any potential problems (chances are they know what typically causes issues for their users).

Comment: Please check the 'domain' key value in App->storage->sessions file.May be its points the localhost.if Yes,plz change with your server domain name.and then try the same... Hope it works:)

Comment: I also agree with Sam. Your problem is a bit weird/peculiar and could also be an issue with your browser. My suggestion is that you should use `Log` to log the user information after `Auth::attempt` as well as in your filter to determine the exact point the issue happens. May provide some clues. Also hope you don't have environment specific settings like using a different auth config for local/production and if you're using file for session storage, ensure that you have proper access settings on 'app/storage'.